# Оптимизация кода галереи (JQuery Powered)

Tags: jquery, html, css

День добрый, написал [простенький скрипт галерей](http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/v5jaz/1/), так как только начал изучать нормально JS то уверен что в коде много хлама, если есть время гляньте, критика и тыканье носом в ошибки приветствуется! спасибо!

Comment: мне не нравится эстетически функция checkButtons, ну и ещё, если бы вы сделали это в форме плагина, то было бы компактнее и проще.

Comment: Eicto спасибо буду копать, если бы прмерно представлял как это организовать в плагин я бы вряд ли задал этот вопрос! Сейчас буду искать маны по написаню плагинов!

Comment: ещё какие-то баги с показом кнопок, если открывать/закрывать.

Comment: вот тут как-то делал пример галереи, не помню почему http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/R9kcN/

Comment: Баги с показом кнопок убрал! http://jsfiddle.net/Cone/xw63k/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите сделать jQuery плагин, могу поделиться заготовкой которую писал для себя. Дополнил комментариями, чтобы было более понятно, что и зачем.

```
; (function ($, undefined) {

    // Название плагина; также имя функции для подключения $(selector).myPlugin( ... )
    var pluginName = 'myPlugin',

    // Стандартные опции
        defaults = {                    
            optionOne: false, message: 'no message set'
        };

    /// Конструктор
    /// element : $, options : {}
    function MyPlugin(element, options) {

        // Сохраняем элемент для последующего использования
        this.element = element;

        // Установка опций
        // Комбинируем стандарты + пользовательские опции
        this.options = $.extend({}, defaults, options);

        // Инициализация плагина
        this.init();
    }

    MyPlugin.prototype = {

        // Пример обработчика событий
        _onClick: function (e) {

            // Для доступа к объекту плагина:
            // var plugin = $(this).data(pluginName);

            alert(pluginName + ' - click - ')

        },
        init: function () {
            // Добавляем обработчик событий
            this.element.on('click', this._onClick);
        },
        test: function(username, message) {
            alert("Dear " + username + ":\n" + message);
        },
        // Функция удаления плагина
        destroy: function () {

            // Снимаем обработчик событий
            this.element.off('click', this._onClick)

            // Удаляем объект плагина из data элемента.
                        .removeData(pluginName);
        }
    };

    // Делаем плагин доступным для всех объектов jQuery
    // Функция обработки элементов к которым нужно подключить плагин
    $.fn[pluginName] = function (options) {

        // Кэшируем аргументы функции
        var args = arguments;

        // Обрабатываем все элементы
        return this.each(function () {

            // Проверяем подключен ли плагин к актуальному элементу
            // Если да, то options это название функции которую нужно вызвать,
            // а args аргумент для этой функции
            var cached = $.data(this, pluginName);
            if (cached) {
                if(options.substring) 
                    cached[options].apply(cached, [].splice.call(args, 1));
                return true;
            }
            // Если плагин не подключен, и идет вызов функции
            // кидаем исключение
            else if(options.substring)
                throw new Error(pluginName + ' не создан для данного элемента');

            // Иначе оборачиваем элемент в объект jQuery 
            cached = $(this);

            // Создаем плагин и сохраняем его в data элемента
            cached.data(pluginName, new MyPlugin(cached, options));

        });
    };

})(jQuery);

/* Использование: 
 *
 *      Создание плагина: 
 *
 *            $(selector).myPlugin({ message: 'Новый плагин' });
 *
 *      Вызов функции: 
 *
 *            $(selector).myPlugin('test', 'Вася', 'Тестовое сообщение');
 *
 *      Удаление плагина:
 *
 *            $(selector).myPlugin('destroy');
 *
*/
```

Демонстрация: http://jsfiddle.net/pbuuy/

---

**Если есть какие-то недочеты, буду рад услышать.**

Comment: Павел, спасибо! Сейчас буду  смотреть, ковырять! Надеюсь что-нибудь толковое выйдет!!

Answer (score 0):

Возьмите лучше любой из существующих. Зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Готовый взять много ума не надо, пока не помучаешься ничему не научишься.

Comment: Опять же проще взять готовую галерею и посмотреть как она реализована.