# Несколько объектов для плагина

Tags: jquery, javascript, плагин

Подскажите, пожалуйста, каким образом можно писать `jq`-плагины, которые использовались бы несколькими объектами в пределах одной страницы.

Например, я написал плагин выезжающей панели http://jsfiddle.net/UAT5F/

Далее я хотел бы чтобы на странице было 2 таких панели. Чтобы код не дублировать хотел бы обойтись тем же самым плагином. Но подключить его хотя бы таким образом http://jsfiddle.net/J6keP/ не получается

Мне не понятно как нужно спроектировать мой плагин

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не так давно здесь был [подобный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/236552/html-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B8-jquery-powered), в ответе я выкладвал свою заготовку для написания плагинов jQuery, посмотрите, если возникнут вопросы, отвечу в комментариях.

Также пример плагина который использует эту заготовку: http://jsfiddle.net/coder13/eauw4/

Comment: объясните пожалуйста вот эту конструкцию
; (function ($, undefined) {
})(jQuery);
мне не понятно зачем здесь аргумент undefined и символ ";"
правильно ли я понимаю, что $ здесь означает сам элемент к которому применяется плагин? то есть через эту функция $ в теле плагина можно обращаться к элементу, например так $.css('background', 'red')

Comment: $ === jQuery, зачем undefined ... [нашел здесь](http://enterprisejquery.com/2010/07/create-your-first-jquery-plugin-part-1-transition-from-everyday-jquery-code-to-base-plugin/)

> Adding ‘undefined’ (yet passing in nothing as the parameter when executing the function) allows us to make sure someone didn’t do this sort of funny business in javascript previous to our function execution:

    undefined = "I'm defined now!!!"; //legal

т.е. защита от переопределения undefined в родительской области видимости (в хроме глобальный undefined не переопределяется)

Comment: @eicto: Все верно.

Comment: то есть как я понял бывают ситуации когда интерпретатор языка выводит в консоль или через алерт сообщение о, том, что переменная не определена(undefined). и если какой-нибудь шутник предварительно передал в плагин значение для undefined, то вывод собщения об ошибке будет некоррктным. так?